# Programatically extend a user's WSO2 Identity Server session?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We are going to be using WSO2 Identity server to authenticate users into a web portal.  The web portal will contain many sso links to other systems.  Currently, the only identity protocol we are using is CAS (From Ellucian).

Our issue is when someone logs into our web portal, using CAS from wso2, then that user browses around through the portal for 10+ minutes, then that user clicks a link to a service relying on the wso2 session, that session has timed out, and the user must log into wso2 again.

Is it possible to programatically extend the user's session by sending something from the web portal periodically?  Like a URL call saying "Hey, I'm still using the wso2 session, don't end it please!".

Answer (score 0):

Any request that you will make from that browser to WSO2 IS from your application e.g. portlet, servlet, that will access session will automatically extend it.

Comment: So an ajax call from the client's browser to https://Our-wso2.domain.edu/cas will extend the session?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the SSO features of IS, it has a default session idle timeout of 15 minutes. You can increase this timeout as described in [1]. As this is a idle timeout any request that access the session in the IS will delay the session expiry time as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36307604/1537365)

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Configuring+Session+Timeout